# Levels instead of factor as values in the dataset R

Tags: r, dataset, levels

I have a data set that look as follow...

[image]

Happened that the last row has one of two values, either `positive` or `negative`, this column is not shown in the image. Each one of those are factors. I need to populate the data set with the levels; `1`, `2`, `3` instead of `x`, `o`, `b`, or what ever the level value might be. Also I need to keep the last column intact with no changes whatsoever. How can I accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
mydf[ ,1:ncol(mydf)-1] <- sapply(mydf[ ,1:ncol(mydf)-1], as.integer)
```

Where `mydf` is the name of your dataframe.

Comment: I modify slightly the code but the library and the logic did addressed my need.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `forcats` package if you don't have it already.

Then repeat for as many variables as necessary the following line:

```
var <- fct_recode(var, 1 = "x", 2 = "o", 3 = "b")
```

Where `var` is the name of the variable in that particular column.